# Using Touch ID with Amazon App

Tags: ios, touch-id

According to the update in the App Store, the Amazon app now supports login via Touch ID. Has anyone figured out how to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application keeps you logged in to your account once you log in unless you log out, but if you do anything that would require a password entry like managing your wish list, a Touch ID prompt comes up giving you the option to use your fingerprint instead of typing in your password

Comment: Note (2016-02-15): I just used the app, went to check out, and was prompted for *both* Touch ID and my password. Seems rather useless to me.

Answer (score 2):

Go to settings, scroll down till you find a list of downloaded apps. Locate and tap Amazon app. You will find toggle switch to turn on/off touch id feature.
Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

I just received this email from Amazon that refutes the existence of the feature:

> Hello,
>
> Thank you for contacting Amazon.  I've researched "Touch ID" feature
>   and found this feature it isn't available with the Amazon Appstore
>   apps at this time. We're constantly adding apps and features to our
>   selection, and features not unavailable now may become available in
>   the future.
>
> I've forwarded your message to our Appstore development team for
>   consideration.
>
> We look forward to seeing you again soon.
>
> Best regards,
>   Devender K

Comment: Umm. The Amazon Appstore is their Android app store that competes with Google Play, and has no bearing on iOS.

Comment: I thought the letter was worded funny. It seems they are more confused about the feature than we are!

Answer (score 1):

Settings>Passwords & Accounts>Website & App Passwords>Tap “+”
 then type www.amazon.com
Then type username (your email address)
Then type a password of your choice

Worked for me. IPhone 6s iOS 13

Answer (score 0):

You're not alone, no one knows how to turn it on (or off!)

[Amazon app for iPhone adds Touch ID support, but nobody knows how to turn it on…or off](http://www.geekwire.com/2014/amazon-app-iphone-gives-new-meaning-1-click-touch-id-support/)

A friend of mine says it works on his iPhone 6+.  And so, I log into the same Amazon app on my iPhone 6, via name and password, I order products, manage my wish list, and *never* see the TouchID interface appear. So strange!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just figured this out (finally), "and yes it does work".  But it seems to be a combination of several of the answers provided above.

Probably the most important thing to point out is Tpoccu's posting.
"The application keeps you logged in to your account once you log in unless you log out", but if you're anything like me and you log out every time you're finished with the App, continue reading...

The first thing you'll need to do is go to Settings and scroll down to the Amazon App on your iPhone 6 (minimum) with an "Up To Date iOS", then scroll down to "Use Biometric authentication when available" and turn that on as Nura suggested.

Once that's done go to Settings/Passwords & Accounts/Website & App Passwords and Tap the “+” (top right) to provide the credentials that the App needs, and type in www.amazon.com under the Website Address and then just type in your Username and Password as Mr D suggested and you're done.

Then the next time you open the Amazon App and tap the Sign In button the App will ask you if you want to associate the App with the password that you saved earlier, just tap Ok and touch the finger print reader and you will be logged into the App automatically.

I hope this helps!